# how to limit search for cities to certain country in Javascript weather app using Openweathermap api

Tags: javascript, html, json

I built a very bare-bones weather app for an assignment in a class I am taking using the OpenWeatherMap API but I find my solution to be very awkward and it doesn't meet all the criteria set by my professor.
My professor told us to use the 5-day / 3-hour forecast in order to display the min/ max temperatures, humidity, weather conditions, and an appropriate icon for the upcoming 5 days but the issue with that is the fact that the said forecast displays its information in 3-hour intervals, meaning the min/max temperatures for each day arent really available to use. (If I am not mistaken)

Additionally, I need to limit the cities available for search to US cities but I don't know how to do that in JS and couldn't find a way to specify it in the API call.

Now because of the way the data is output by the 5-day/3-hour call, I felt forced to create an element for each day and give it its corresponding data like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Weather app</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Weather forecast</h1>
    <form id="cityForm">
      <label for="city">Enter City Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="city" name="city" />
      <br /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script>
      function getWeather(query) {
        var url =
          "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=" +
          query +
          "&units=imperial&APPID=56866f8407bb1e2d63330f3c046f35af";
        fetch(url)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => displayWeather(data)); //call displayWeather function
      }

      document
        .getElementById("cityForm")
        .addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
          event.preventDefault(); // prevent the form from submitting
          var city = document.getElementById("city").value; // get the city name from the input field
          getWeather(city);
        });

      function displayWeather(weather) {
        console.log(weather);
        var resultContainer = document.querySelector("#output");
        var cityName = document.createElement("h2");
        resultContainer.append(cityName);
        var forecastDate1 = document.createElement("p"); // Creating elements
        var forecastDate2 = document.createElement("p");
        var forecastDate3 = document.createElement("p");
        var forecastDate4 = document.createElement("p");
        var forecastDate5 = document.createElement("p");
        cityName.textContent = weather.city.name;
        var icon = document.createElement("img");
        var iconUrl =
          "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" +
          weather.list[0].weather[0].icon +
          ".png";
        icon.setAttribute("src", iconUrl);

        var description = document.createElement("p");
        var day1 = new Date(weather.list[0].dt * 1000);
        const month1 = day1.getMonth() + 1;
        const firstDay = day1.getDate();
        const year1 = day1.getFullYear();
        const outputDateStr1 = `${month1.toString().padStart(2, "0")}/${firstDay
          .toString()
          .padStart(2, "0")}/${year1.toString()}`;

        var day2 = new Date(weather.list[8].dt * 1000);
        const month2 = day2.getMonth() + 1;
        const secondDay = day2.getDate();
        const year2 = day2.getFullYear();
        const outputDateStr2 = `${month2
          .toString()
          .padStart(2, "0")}/${secondDay
          .toString()
          .padStart(2, "0")}/${year2.toString()}`;

        var day3 = new Date(weather.list[16].dt * 1000);
        const month3 = day3.getMonth() + 1;
        const thirdDay = day3.getDate();
        const year3 = day3.getFullYear();
        const outputDateStr3 = `${month3.toString().padStart(2, "0")}/${thirdDay
          .toString()
          .padStart(2, "0")}/${year3.toString()}`;

        var day4 = new Date(weather.list[24].dt * 1000);
        const month4 = day4.getMonth() + 1;
        const fourthDay = day4.getDate();
        const year4 = day4.getFullYear();
        const outputDateStr4 = `${month4
          .toString()
          .padStart(2, "0")}/${fourthDay
          .toString()
          .padStart(2, "0")}/${year4.toString()}`;

        var day5 = new Date(weather.list[32].dt * 1000);
        const month5 = day5.getMonth() + 1;
        const fifthDay = day5.getDate();
        const year5 = day5.getFullYear();
        const outputDateStr5 = `${month5.toString().padStart(2, "0")}/${fifthDay
          .toString()
          .padStart(2, "0")}/${year5.toString()}`;

        forecastDate1.textContent = `${outputDateStr1} 
        Min ${weather.list[0].main.temp_min} F 
        Max: ${weather.list[0].main.temp_max} F 
        Humidity: ${weather.list[0].main.humidity}% 
        Weather conditions: ${weather.list[0].weather[0].description}`;
        var icon1 = document.createElement("img");
        var iconUrl1 =
          "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" +
          weather.list[0].weather[0].icon +
          ".png";
        icon1.setAttribute("src", iconUrl1);
        forecastDate1.append(icon1);

        forecastDate2.textContent = `${outputDateStr2} 
        Min ${weather.list[8].main.temp_min} F 
        Max: ${weather.list[8].main.temp_max} F 
        Humidity:  ${weather.list[8].main.humidity}% 
        Weather conditions: ${weather.list[8].weather[0].description}`;
        var icon2 = document.createElement("img");
        var iconUrl2 =
          "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" +
          weather.list[8].weather[0].icon +
          ".png";
        icon2.setAttribute("src", iconUrl2);
        forecastDate2.append(icon2);

        forecastDate3.textContent = `${outputDateStr3} 
        Min ${weather.list[16].main.temp_min} F 
        Max: ${weather.list[16].main.temp_max} F 
        Humidity:  ${weather.list[16].main.humidity}% 
        Weather conditions: ${weather.list[16].weather[0].description}`;
        var icon3 = document.createElement("img");
        var iconUrl3 =
          "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" +
          weather.list[16].weather[0].icon +
          ".png";
        icon3.setAttribute("src", iconUrl3);
        forecastDate3.append(icon3);

        forecastDate4.textContent = `${outputDateStr4} 
        Min ${weather.list[24].main.temp_min} F 
        Max: ${weather.list[24].main.temp_max} F 
        Humidity:  ${weather.list[24].main.humidity}% 
        Weather conditions: ${weather.list[24].weather[0].description}`;
        var icon4 = document.createElement("img");
        var iconUrl4 =
          "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" +
          weather.list[24].weather[0].icon +
          ".png";
        icon4.setAttribute("src", iconUrl4);
        forecastDate4.append(icon4);

        forecastDate5.textContent = `${outputDateStr5} 
        Min ${weather.list[32].main.temp_min} F 
        Max: ${weather.list[32].main.temp_max} F 
        Humidity:  ${weather.list[32].main.humidity}% 
        Weather conditions: ${weather.list[32].weather[0].description}`;
        var icon5 = document.createElement("img");
        var iconUrl5 =
          "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" +
          weather.list[32].weather[0].icon +
          ".png";
        icon5.setAttribute("src", iconUrl5);
        forecastDate5.append(icon5);

        resultContainer.append(forecastDate1);
        resultContainer.append(forecastDate2);
        resultContainer.append(forecastDate3);
        resultContainer.append(forecastDate4);
        resultContainer.append(forecastDate5);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a screenshot of the data I get from the 5-day / 3-hour API call. You can find the temp_min/ temp_max under main in the second item of the array.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q={city name},{country code}&appid={API key}
```

I'd advise playing with country code in the request.